# Why do we study irreducibility of polynomials? What are some real-life applications?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Irreducibility of polynomial functions seems like one of the major topics in introductory abstract algebra, and there are many theorems (such as Eisenstein's Criterion, etc) on testing whether a polynomial is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x], \mathbb{R}[x],$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$, etc.

I wonder, why do we care so much about irreducibility? What are some of the applications (preferably in engineering or physics, but other areas are also great)?

Thanks!

Comment: To make a field of size $p^k$ where $p$ is a prime, you take an irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ of degree $k$ and form the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_p[x] / f(x)$. Finite fields of this kind are used right throughout coding theory, error correction, and so on.

Comment: More nonconstructively, to get the finite field of size $p^n$, take the splitting field of $x^{(p^n)} - x$ extending $\mathbb{F}_p$. It’s straightforward to see that the roots of this polynomial form a field with exactly $p^n$ elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Polynomial codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code) are error detection and correction codes that start by choosing a finite field of prime power order, $GF(p^n)$.  The easiest way to explicitly construct such a field in which you can actually compute is to construct a non-prime field.  For instance, if $P(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n> 1$, then $GF(p^n) = GF(p)[X]/P(X)$ is a finite field of order $p^n$.  (It doesn't matter which irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ you use -- you get the same field, but the names of some of the elements seem different.)

Polynomial codes include

- [cyclic codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_code), which give [cyclic redundancy checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)(CRCs).  iSCSI and SCTP have incorporated CRCs.;
- [BCH codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code) and [Reed-Solomon codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction), which are used in radio communication, [CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc)s, [DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD)s, [HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)s, [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)s, some 2-d barcodes, e.g. [QR codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), data transmission and reconstruction, and other forms of data storage and retrieval.

Comment: +1. I might add: You can get some intuition about why finite fields might be useful by noting that if we choose $p=2$, then finite fields have size $2^n$, and so are naturally in bijection with binary strings, i.e., whatever data we care about.  So various computations over finite fields become data manipulation algorithms.